# How to dump game data before closing C++ Windows

Tags: c++, console

I am working on a project in which I put my data (I.E. Game world, mobs) into text files, which are read in when I run the game. This works perfectly fine. The game saves the data when I hit a key that exits the game loop, basically saving and then closing the game. However, I habitually hit the X on the top right of the console, and this obviously causes the game to close without saving. My question is, is there any way to run a function when somebody hits the close button on the console, and then close the program? I am working on Windows XP, C++, Console Program.

Comment: The game is a console application?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, totally possible for beginners!  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696117/what-happens-when-you-close-a-c-console-application

Comment: Why not use auto save features periodically?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes this is console

Comment: @camdixon I could, but I am trying to make this program as efficient as possible, and auto saves aren't necessary if I can figure this out. However, I may have to go with auto saves if this fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Closing a c++ console app with the "x" in the top corner throws an
>   CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT which you could catch and process if you set a
>   control handler using the [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. In there
>   you could override the close functionality and perform whatever you
>   wished to do, and then optionally still perform the default behavior.

[What happens when you close a c++ console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696117/what-happens-when-you-close-a-c-console-application)

Comment: I will try to research this... don't know how to use it. Time to go googling! Thanks though.