# Call function right before termination c++

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, termination

Is there a way to call a function at termination(clicking on the red X of the console) of an non-Object-oriented console application(simple main program)?

Maybe to catch the message of the red X and handle it then...

Thanks!

Comment: _Clicking on the X of the console_ doesn't mean exit necessarily. Please be specific on what you've done, what's the problem you're facing, instead of being vague.

Comment: Why don't you describe your problem instead of the solution you have in mind...

Comment: signal() might work, but won't stop it closing. It depends what signal it gets by closing the console.

Comment: Using a static variable with a destructor seems like the obvious solution, but since the problem isn't really clean, it's hard to say.

Comment: "non-Object-oriented console application" : what does that mean ? If you use C++, you can have objects. Then, you could do what @JamesKanze suggests.

Comment: You'll have to rely on platform specific APIs. See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696117/what-happens-when-you-close-a-c-console-application).

Comment: Hi! Would the correct title here be "Call function when user clicks [X] on the windows console window" ?

Comment: What if the X isn't red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are on Windows and have a console application running inside the normal console window, and then click on the Close Button (`[X]`) this will generate a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`.

You can handle these by installing a Console Event Handler with the [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using atexit():

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/

Or maybe a destructor of a global object.