# How to capture application close event for c++ command line project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, command-line, command-prompt

I am developing c++ command line project in visual studio.
I need to capture application closing event (closing application with CTRL+Z or closing command line window while running the application).

My App look like:

```
  int main()
    {
       //crete app object, will open some files and run the code.
       myApp app;
       app.run();

       getchar();
    }
```

If I close the application explicitly as I mentioned above, myApp destructor will  not be executing. so I need some way to capture this closing event in my application (Like QObject::closeEvent() in Qt).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to throw a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` on windows, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696117/what-happens-when-you-close-a-c-console-application) is something that may help you.

Comment: Ctrl+Z just means to end STDIN and close the handle.  It's totally application-specific what it does after that.  For closing the command window, see the link that @JeffreyBencteux posted.

Comment: `atexit` function specifies function which is automatically called without arguments when the program terminates normally.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual case destructor is not caused for objects created in **`main()`**. But there is a good & elegant solution - you can put your code into the **extra parentheses**, and then the destructor will be invoked:

```
int main()
{
    {        
        myApp app;
        app.run();

        getchar();
    } // At this point, the object's destructor is invoked
}
```