# how to prevent Ctrl+Break/Ctrl+C from closing both programs if one was launched from another by system() or CreateProcess()?

Tags: c++, windows, console

This is test example:

(1). simple program doing endless loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int counter = 0;
  while (1) cout << ++counter << ": endless loop..." <<endl;
}
```

(2). another program that launches above example through `system()` command:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  system("endless_loop.exe");
  cout << "back to main program" << endl;
}
```

When doing `Ctrl+Break` on this program text `back to main program` doesn't show.
How to restrict this key combination to inside process and return execution pointer back to main app ?

Another thing is that I don't always have control over source code of inside program, so I can't change things there.

Comment: Could you not register different signal handlers for SIGINT in both programs? This was already discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181413).

Comment: You'll need to detach the started program from your console.  Best done with CreateProcess and the DETACHED_PROCESS option.  Not otherwise wrapped by the CRT.

Comment: @Hans: I would expect DETACHED_PROCESS to result in control-break still interrupting the parent process but not the child process, exactly the opposite of what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this::

```
#include <signal.h>

 ...

signal (SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

After the `signal()` call, the program ignores Ctrl-Break.  On Linux, ignoring signals propagates to child processes through `fork()`/`exec()`.

I would expect Windows to reset the default signal handling on `exec()` due to the way the O/S + runtime library work.  So if you want the child to ignore *Break*, add the code above to it too.