# Can i read the exit value from the console application?

Tags: visual-c++, operating-system, windows-xp

I want to read the exit value from my console application to exit all the related threads with that application before exit.

[image]

Comment: Well you could always write to a logfile.

Comment: This is an OS question, not a C or C++ question. Can you label the question with whatever OS you're using?

Comment: You can review this article [How to handle a ctrl break signal][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181413/how-to-handle-a-ctrl-break-signal-in-a-command-line-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This work for me on Windows try it

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace
{
    volatile sig_atomic_t exit;

    void signal_handler(int sig)
    {
        signal(sig, signal_handler);
        exit= 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
#ifdef SIGBREAK
   signal(SIGBREAK, signal_handler);
#endif


   while (!exit)
   {
       /* do something */
   }
   // Catch signal here
}
```

Comment: @GeniusIDS lol did you just copy paste the post that i linked to?

Comment: @KarthikT lol no i just explain in codes the code from previous link i posted [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181413/how-to-handle-a-ctrl-break-signal-in-a-command-line-interface)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298498/c-console-breaking. The standard library you need to use is [csignal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/csignal)

What you can do is register for signals which force your app to close (SIGTERM) and perform logic there, like exiting your multiple threads. [This post suggests that this should work with windows as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181594/1520364)

You could also register a function with [atexit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) which seems to catch normal exit from main() etc, not sure if closing the terminal will count as "normal exit".

Comment: i want to catch the exit signal so i can closed all related programs before exit.

Comment: @abdo.eng2006210 yes, and adding a signal handler for SIGTERM will do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* Ok so it seems you want to be notified as soon as the process exits. Sorry, I misread your question due to the term "exit value". Well if you start the process via `CreateProcess()` API, you should be able to do `WaitForSingleObject()` on the handle. This function will block until the process exited. So you can place all the code which you want to be executed after the process stopped after this call, and all should be fine.

If you in fact want the exit code of a process (`return X` in `main()`):

Programmatically, you can use `GetExitCodeProcess()` from WinAPI:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx

In the shell, use the `%errorlevel%` variable.